# Can UI interact while program loop through several task

Tags: python-3.x, loops, user-input

I´m developing a program that handles many task in a sequence. I call this mode "AutoMode". But i need to let the user take control and start using the program manual, through menu options, and finally choose "AutoMode" again.

How can I interrupt the "AutoMode" without stopping the program executing. Guess input() will keep the program wait for ever for user to make an input and the rest of the code will stop executing?

Any suggestions?

Comment: it should be running as a separate thread / process, so that your main process can be listening for the keyboard strokes and then instruct the other thread / process to pause the execution. Both threads and processes can be suspended and moved to waiting state. Please show what you have tried till now.

Comment: Thanks @SamridhTuladhar
As brand new to asking question on stackoverflow I made an anser to my question explaning one solution that will work, but not satesfied by the way it works. It needs several keypress to react so not fully what I am looking for.
This task that is executet are quite heavy and takes some time to sycle through so your thread/process suggestion might be a better path.

Comment: I checked your solution, and while it does get the job done, you can see that for every "interrupt" it causes a 2 second sleep, and in that duration, anything that you pressed would be ignored, also, you have an additional `time.sleep(0.5)` that causes even more slowness. So, please look into other thread / process based approaches.

Comment: Thanks @SamridhTuladhar for your comment. Yes time.sleep(2) simulates what is going on in the full aplication. Seems that keyboard will not work while program is in other function called from the keyboard function. 
Think you are spot on with thread.  Must find some documentation and dive in to it.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that solve this issue, but seems to need several keyboard interacts.
In example below this results in many keypress to get the while loop to enter the if statement and take the program back to main menu.

```
    import keyboard
    import time
    
    my_counter = 1
    while True:
        my_counter += 1
        if keyboard.is_pressed('h'):
            print("Letter H was pushed")
            time.sleep(2)
            break

        print("Something is going on... ", my_counter)
        time.sleep(0.5)

    print("Simulate user interupt and return to main menu...")
```